# New Samsung Washer Smells

Tags: washing-machine, new-home, odors

I am concerned because our new Samsung washing machine (front loading, stackable, stacked on the bottom) absolutely REEKS of chemicals; the closest I can think of is paint thinner. I expected a "new plastic" or "new machine" smell when we purchased a new set (having had them before) but this odor is overwhelming. I was on the floor in front of the machine to load it and when I opened it, the odor was strong enough to actually make me feel a little ill. Is this normal, something that will go away, or should I be worried about this? If it's normal, what's the most effective way to get rid of the odor? We are a week behind due to delivery issues and we're starting to run out of clothes....

Comment: Check that the hot and cold water hoses are not reversed. If the hot water line is connected to the cold intake, it may be going through components that were not rated for high temperatures resulting in burnt plastic smells.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a new Amana top loading washing machine! The answers below sound quite reasonable. I found a product EnviroKlenz Washing Machine Deodorizer & Cleaner that claims to deal with this issue. https://enviroklenz.com/why-does-my-washing-machine-smell-like-chemicals What I have found is that if I make the laundry room warmer by doing a bake out, I really notice the rubber odor. I'm trying white vinegar now and have it just sitting for a bit. I was thinking of returning this washer but I may try the EnviroKlenz first.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for all things to smell a little bit when they are brand new. (Think "new car smell"), but in your case, I think this goes past a factory fresh scent. You should consult your washing machine manual on how to run a "cleaner" cycle. Typically it is like 1/4 cup bleach or something on an empty cycle. This should get rid of any smells coming from it!

Comment: I agree.  First front loads should be kept open to dry out.  Second I bleach mine on an empty cycle at least once a month.  I do put a lot more than a 1/4 cup in though.

Comment: DMoore: Agreed! I read on the bleach bottle though that failure to use bleach as directed is a felony, so I never put in more than the recommended amount!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's normal to have such a strong smell when you use the washing machine. Something must be wrong. You can call the Samsung service center to get some suggestion. Or you can check the [Samsung Washing machine manual](http://www.manualbirds.com/manuals/samsung-b1213j-user-manual-264226-16) to find the problem. I don't know the model of your washing machine, but I show you a part of my washing machine manual. You can clean yours under the instruction. Hope it will work. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little dated, but the smell was likely due to the design choice of using cheaper elastomer (rubber) materials, especially for the door seal. I just purchased a brand new high end Samsung washer and dryer set, and I am having the same problem. Not only do the appliances reek of rubber smell, but my first load of clothes has the exact same smell, even after hanging on the line, over night. There is no telling how long it will take for the smell to air out of them, or how long it will take for the washer and dryer to stop smelling. Had the seals been made of a high quality elastomer, such as one that was platinum cured, they would have no smell, and I'd have gladly paid much more for the set.